# Removing Item from array with Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array like this :

```
var array = [1,20,50,60,78,90];
var id = 50;
```

How can i remove the id from the array and return a new array that does not have the value of the id in new array?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For the complex solutions you can use method [`_.reject()`](http://underscorejs.org/#reject), so that you can put a custom logic into callback:

```
var removeValue = function(array, id) {
    return _.reject(array, function(item) {
        return item === id; // or some complex logic
    });
};
var array = [1, 20, 50, 60, 78, 90];
var id = 50;
console.log(removeValue(array, id));
```

For the simple cases use more convenient method [`_.without()`](http://underscorejs.org/#without):

```
var array = [1, 20, 50, 60, 78, 90];
var id = 50;
console.log(_.without(array, id));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f0t0n/tNKdz/)

Answer (score 14):

[_filter](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) works too. It's the opposite of [_reject](http://underscorejs.org/#reject).

```
var array = [1,20,50,60,78,90];
var id = 50;

var result = _.filter(array, function(x) { return x != id });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kman007_us/WzaJz/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can use **splice**, though it is not underscore's API:

```
arrayObject.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX)
```

In your example:

```
var index = _.indexOf(array, id);
array.splice(index, 1);
```